# Using loop counter as part of a variable's name in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to generate a bunch of variables that will be operated on. Started with 2 variables, 4, 8,16 and its about time I put the variable generation in a loop.

The variable is acting as a storage for the index of an array.

So a thread wakes up, picks up a variable and says "variable_0" is the first index, and stores location 24 inside of it.

This is usually done like so. This variable goes on and is used multiple times later on.

variable_0 = get_index(threadid)

Once I have 16 of such variables, its a pain and ugly to see that line repeated more than once. So I thought I'd put in a loop and tried it with 2 methods.

**1. EVAL**

```
for i in 0..15 do 
    eval("variable_#{i} = get_index(threadid)")
end
```

Does not work at all.

**2. instance_variable_set**

```
for i in 0..15 do
    index_name = "variable_#{i}"
    index_val = get_index(threadid)
    instance_variable_set("#{index_name}", :index_val)
end
```

This doesn't work either, since a later statement prints "variable not found " pretty much.

Is there a good way to go about doing this?

Due to restrictions later down the line, I cannot use an array for this, each variable has to be constructed as a single variable, so no arrays or anything like that would work

Comment: This is a common XY-problem asked repeatedly. You should use an array to keep all the values.

Comment: Variables are used by external software, it doesn't take in array elements. I mean I wrote this above as well, its a limitation I can't overcome, its not my own unwillingness to work with arrays....

Comment: But you seem to have freedom with variable naming (local or instance). It is a strange situation that you nevertheless do not have freedom of using an array. Your situation is not clear.

Comment: By the way, how does it make sense to have a variable name restricted to certain a format by an external software? Especially, local variables' scope is the method body or a block. I can't imagine a situation where you are calling an external software from Ruby, and the (local) variable name matters.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to have a set of variables containing a counter instead of just an array? Why is @variable_0 better than @variables[0]?

Comment: Variable is passed to an external ruby function which then calls java. Attempting to pass an element of an array to the functions produces an error.

Comment: @JohnNikolaou that doesn't make much sense. You are passing the object that is assigned to the variable, not the variable itself. Therefore, it is irrelevant if the object is assigned to a variable or element of an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out it is not possible to create local variables dynamically in Ruby, you could set up a binding as well if you're looking for another method of achieving this.

With **eval**

```
b = binding
10.times do |i|
  eval("var#{i} = 'foo'", b)
end

> eval("var1", b)
=> "foo"

> eval("local_variables", b)
=> [:var9, :var8, :var7, :var6, :var5, :var4, :var3, :var2, :var1, :var0, :b, :_]
```

Without **eval**

```
b = binding
10.times do |i|
  b.local_variable_set("var#{i}", 'foo')
end

> b.local_variable_get('var1')
=> "foo"

> b.local_variables
=> [:var9, :var8, :var7, :var6, :var5, :var4, :var3, :var2, :var1, :var0, :b, :_]
```

Comment: correct answer but not the "nice" one. I rly dont like use `eval` this way. but +1

Comment: Agreed eval always seems *evil*, however this is the way as described by ruby docs (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Binding.html)

Comment: I've updated it without eval as well, seems it was possible after all!

Answer (score 2):

Your second example is almost valid. You forgot `@` for instance variable name and you passed a symbol as value instead the value itself.

```
for i in 0..15 do
  index_val = "some value #{i}"
  instance_variable_set("@variable_#{i}", index_val)
end

puts @variable_4 # "some value"
```

https://repl.it/BnLO/6

Comment: This is a terrible pattern, you should have answered something that would help the OP to do better code, like creating an array of values and operation on them.

Comment: True that. But poster has expressed that `Array` can't be used. Who am I to judge?

Comment: You don't need the colon in `:"@variable_#{i}"`. The method accepts strings as well as symbols.

Comment: Thank you @sawa, corrected.

Comment: @jturolla Yes, this is terrible pattern, but he ask a question and this is correct answer. Ofc, better way is to use `Hash` or `Array`.

Comment: This works for me, thanks, I do try to write as good code as possible and to improve, but when you're given a very strict external non-modifiable framework, you try to survive